# can not open axml file in visual studio by Designer , android apps

Tags: android, xamarin

When open layout or add new layout, designer can't open it,
it show me error
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: o

[image]

error message

```
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: o
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIUnknownForObjectNative(Object o, Boolean onlyInContext)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.UpdateD3DImageFromSharedSurface() in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:line 140
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows.WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.RenderDesignerItemVisual(DesignerItem item) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Windows\WindowsAndroidSurfaceRenderer.cs:line 131
   at Xamarin.Designer.Windows.WpfSurfaceRenderer.QueueRender(DesignerItem item) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer\Xamarin.Designer.Windows\WpfSurfaceRenderer.cs:line 361
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSurface.HandleSessionImageChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSurface.cs:line 229
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.OnImageChanged() in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line 2321
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.HandleRendered(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\A\_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line 1381
```

Axml file code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px" />
```

visual studio 2017
sdk platform [link image](https://scontent.fbsr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27751758_729981343874220_4277438641560629923_n.jpg?oh=3f9c88169637029cd1964e6d2adfa043&oe=5ADA6FD8)

sdk tools  [link imgage](https://scontent.fbsr4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27750353_729981297207558_8979667342117191814_n.jpg?oh=5913b56452ebbf6a3fb8ba2c69ef41b5&oe=5B121AB6)

mainfast code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
          package="App1.App1" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          android:installLocation="auto"> 
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="25" /> 
    <application android:allowBackup="true" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
    </application> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: Additional details like Xamarin Studio version and OS related information helps to answer better

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: Op edit your question instead of adding the additional details to the comments section

Comment: What is your Xamarin version?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?